# Does useCallback accept an object from props in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have a reusable component which receives an object prop in react, in this reusable component i have a useCallback, but i am not sure if it's correct since it's an object, and since there's referential equality thing I am confused.

```
const SukiCustomer = ({ contact, source, sukiPhoneNumbers, isCreditFlow }) => {
  const appTheme = useThemeContext();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const isSukiCustomer = sukiPhoneNumbers.includes(contact.phone_number);
  const isAllCustomers = source === ALL;
  const isCredit = source === CREDIT;
  const isPromo = source === PROMO;
  const dueAmount = contact.totalDebit - contact.totalCredit;
  const displayDueAmount = getFormattedPesos(dueAmount);

  const onPress = useCallback(() => {
    const handleIsCredit = async () => {
      try {
        const parameters = {
          id: contact.id,
          first_name: contact.first_name,
          last_name: contact.last_name,
          phone_number: contact.phone_number,
          totalCredit: contact.totalCredit,
          totalDebit: contact.totalDebit,
          'Screen Name': 'SukiCustomers',
        };
        await selectSukiContact({ parameters });
        await viewSukiTransactionHistory({ parameters });
        timeToInteractionUtils.setTTIStartTime({
          key: keys.TTI_START_SUKI_TRANSACTION_HISTORY,
        });
        navigation.navigate('TransactionHistory', {
          contact,
          fromScreen: leanPlumConstants.screenNames.SukiListaActivity,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(FILE_PATH, error);
      }
    };

    const handleIsNotSukiCustomer = async () => {
      const parameters = {
        ...contact,
        button_name: 'Add',
      };
      await addSukiContact({ parameters }).catch(error => {
        console.error(FILE_PATH, error);
      });
      timeToInteractionUtils.setTTIStartTime({
        key: keys.TTI_START_ADD_CONTACT_ACTIVITY,
      });
      const origin = isCreditFlow ? CREDIT : SUKI;
      navigation.navigate('AddSukiCustomer', {
        contact,
        source: origin,
      });
    };

    if (!isSukiCustomer) {
      handleIsNotSukiCustomer();
    } else if (isCredit) {
      handleIsCredit();
    }
  }, [contact, navigation, isCreditFlow, isCredit, isSukiCustomer]);
```

This actually works but i am just not sure if this is correct way or maybe i should deconstruct on top of component:

```
 const { id, first_name, last_name, phone_number, totalCredit, totalDebit } =
    contact;
```

and on useCallback pass them and refer to them and not the object prop?

```
[
    id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    phone_number,
    totalCredit,
    totalDebit,
    active_services,
    suki_id,
    id,
    navigation,
    isCreditFlow,
    isCredit,
    isSukiCustomer,
  ]);
```

Pls help me improve my code

Comment: where are you calling the `useCallBack` function ? In the same component or a different component ?

Comment: If you are using it in the same component where u defined, then the `useCallBack` is not necessary as it will re-render when the component renders.

Comment: Hello, I am using in the same component @Thinker

Comment: If you using it in different component, say referring the `useCallBack` into another component, then you have to add all the dependent variables in the `useCallBack` dependency. So, the `useCallBack` only re-render when the variables are updated.

Comment: bro you dont nest callback functions

Comment: Do you even *need* `useCallback` here?

Comment: @Bergi actually it's not very clear to me when is the appropriate use case of useCallback, i thought u should always do it like you do useEffect

Comment: @gpbaculio The recommendation is actually not to use it until you need it. You'll need it when something (`useEffect`, `useMemo`, `useCallback` etc) uses the identity of the callback as a dependency

Comment: @Bergi ah i see in this case, the dependencies are not used by other hooks, so if it's you, you would not do useCallback?

Comment: No, the question is: Is `onPress` used as a dependency anywhere (including components to which it is passed as a prop)? You haven't shown that code yet.

Comment: @Bergi onPress useCallback is only used like this inside the component:

<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}

Comment: @gpbaculio And now the question is what `TouchableOpacity` does with `onPress`. Does it care whether the function identity changes or not?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you move out each callback function outside of your onPress function  and wrap them with useCallback.

Something like below:

```
const SukiCustomer = ({ contact, source, sukiPhoneNumbers, isCreditFlow }) => {
  const appTheme = useThemeContext()
  const navigation = useNavigation()

  const isSukiCustomer = sukiPhoneNumbers.includes(contact.phone_number)
  const isAllCustomers = source === ALL
  const isCredit = source === CREDIT
  const isPromo = source === PROMO
  const dueAmount = contact.totalDebit - contact.totalCredit
  const displayDueAmount = getFormattedPesos(dueAmount)

  const handleIsCredit = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const parameters = {
        id: contact.id,
        first_name: contact.first_name,
        last_name: contact.last_name,
        phone_number: contact.phone_number,
        totalCredit: contact.totalCredit,
        totalDebit: contact.totalDebit,
        'Screen Name': 'SukiCustomers',
      }
      await selectSukiContact({ parameters })
      await viewSukiTransactionHistory({ parameters })
      timeToInteractionUtils.setTTIStartTime({
        key: keys.TTI_START_SUKI_TRANSACTION_HISTORY,
      })
      navigation.navigate('TransactionHistory', {
        contact,
        fromScreen: leanPlumConstants.screenNames.SukiListaActivity,
      })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(FILE_PATH, error)
    }
  },[contact])

  const handleIsNotSukiCustomer = useCallback(async () => {
    const parameters = {
      ...contact,
      button_name: 'Add',
    }
    await addSukiContact({ parameters }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(FILE_PATH, error)
    })
    timeToInteractionUtils.setTTIStartTime({
      key: keys.TTI_START_ADD_CONTACT_ACTIVITY,
    })
    const origin = isCreditFlow ? CREDIT : SUKI
    navigation.navigate('AddSukiCustomer', {
      contact,
      source: origin,
    })
  },[isCreditFlow, contact])

  const onPress = useCallback(() => {
    if (!isSukiCustomer) {
      handleIsNotSukiCustomer()
    } else if (isCredit) {
      handleIsCredit()
    }
  }, [isCredit, isSukiCustomer, handleIsNotSukiCustomer, handleIsCredit])
}
```